# Simple Math Android App Not Working

Tags: android, math

I am new to Android developing and I am trying to make a simple app as practice. All it consists of is you type one number into the first box, a number into the second box, press a button and the result prints into a textview. The problem is, when I press the send button Nothing is happening. Eclipse is not showing any errors, nor is LogCat. So I am officially stumped as to why when I run this I'm not getting anything out. Hopefully you guys can help.

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="172dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="First Number:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Second Number:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="Calc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the Java:

```
package com.example.mathbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    Button sum;
    EditText num1, num2;
    TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void main(String[] args){

    num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

num1.getText().toString();
num2.getText().toString();

    int x =Integer.parseInt("num1");
    int y =Integer.parseInt("num2");

    int nas = x + y;

    tv.setText(nas);



    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {}

});}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing the wrong string..

```
num1.getText().toString();
num2.getText().toString();

int x =Integer.parseInt("num1");
int y =Integer.parseInt("num2");
```

What you are doing now is parsing the strings "num1" and "num2" into a string and I don't think that is what you want. So it should be:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
int y = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
```

And also move the code into the onCreate() method just like @AndroidEnthusiastic suggested.

Comment: Thanks! Not only did it work, but it cleaned the code up nicely!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

For Android it is a simple method,not an entry point that by the way supposed to be :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

I can't see that you are calling your main method in your code.

```
num1.getText().toString();
num2.getText().toString();
```

You just get the values without assigning it to any properties.
This code is totally wrong.

I suggest you to start from the beginning with official Android Training : [Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hye Diamond you are doing something wrong. Its ok your beginner. see you are creating main mothod. In java main method `public static void main` get executed first but here once activity created oncreate method will execute. So you can do it in following ways:

```
 //inside oncreate method do like this
  num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
 findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
   int val1 = num1.getText().toString();
   int val2 = num2.getText().toString();

int x =Integer.parseInt(val1);
int y =Integer.parseInt(val2);

int nas = x + y;

tv.setText(nas);
    }
```

});

this might be help you. It's not tested. May be you have to do some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution

```
package com.example.mathbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    Button sum;
    EditText num1, num2;
    TextView tv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                num1.getText().toString();
                num2.getText().toString();

                int x =Integer.parseInt("num1");
                int y =Integer.parseInt("num2");

                int nas = x + y;

                tv.setText(nas);
            }
        });
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Please take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Thanks! I had to swap the **int** statements for what @D. Wonnink suggested above and then mod the **setText** to `tv.setText(String.valueOf(nas));` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Find this code.. hope it helps

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button sum;
EditText num1, num2;
TextView tv;
String x;
String y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    sum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    sum.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
}

class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Integer nas;
        x = num1.getText().toString();
        y = num2.getText().toString();
        nas = Integer.parseInt(x) + Integer.parseInt(y);
        tv.setText(nas.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class add extends Activity {
Button     button1;
 EditText   txtbox1,txtbox2;
 TextView tv;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 txtbox1=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtbox1);
 button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl1);
 txtbox2=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtbox2);
 button1.setOnClickListener(new clicker());    
 }
class  clicker implements Button.OnClickListener
{           
public void onClick(View v)
{
 String a,b;
 Integer vis;
 a =  txtbox1.getText().toString();
 b =  txtbox2.getText().toString();    
 vis =  Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b);    
 tv.setText(vis.toString());    
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Pasting some code, with the instruction "try this" does not answer the question.  What have you changed?  Why?  How does it address the OP?

Comment: Hello Simon, see pasting code is not my concept i wanna to help diamond playboy to achieve just add two numbers. AndyFaizan also accept my code . so it's no need to down vote.

Comment: Believe it or not I started out with that exact code...it gave me a ton of errors so I went about fixing it and thats how I ended up in this mess...lol

Answer (score -1):

Please refrain from using the main function. It's not really required in an activity class and also not a general practice. @AndroidEnthusiastic has given the correct code.

Added:
Since the aforementioned answer of mine was downvoted, I'll go ahead and just tell you what you've done wrong in your code(there's a lot of code in the other answers given here).

```
            num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        num1.getText().toString();//Store this in a string say a
        num2.getText().toString();//Store this in a string say b

    /*you're actually the passing the literal "num1" or "num2". Something which you don't want.
    Instead, pass the strings a and b instead of num1 and num2 respectively*/
            int x =Integer.parseInt("num1");
            int y =Integer.parseInt("num2");

            int nas = x + y;

            tv.setText(nas);



            findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                /*You need to put the code here. i.e. You need to take the values from the
editTexts and store them in strings and finally integers when the button is clicked.*/
    }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
int x =Integer.valueof(""+num1.getText().toString());
int y =Integer.valueof(""+num2.getText().toString());

int nas = x + y;

tv.setText(""+String.valueof(nas));
```

Comment: Pasting some code, with the instruction "try this" does not answer the question.  What have you changed?  Why?  How does it address the OP?